# How to count created node XSL?

Tags: xslt

I was asking myself a question. 
I'm on project where I've to transform a .XML file into an other one (after a treatment) but I've to do a numbered list. I know the count(//node) function but I don't think we can count the created nodes with.

For example this is what my .xsl looks like :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Type>
        <List>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="PartOne" select="/Stuff/Info/TypeA"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="PartOneBis" select="/Stuff/Info/TypeB"/>
        </List>
        <AnotherList>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="PartTwo" select="/Stuff/Info/TypeB"/>
        </AnotherList>
    </Type>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="PartOne" match="/Stuff/Info/TypeA">
    <PartOne indexlist="{position()-1}">
        ... treatment ...
    </PartOne>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="PartOneBis" match="/Stuff/Info/TypeB">
    <xsl:if test="TypeB_Indice != 'stuff'">
        <PartOne indexlist="{count(//TypeA) + position()-1}">
            ... treatment ...
        </PartOne>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="PartTwo" match="/Stuff/Info/TypeB">
    <xsl:if test="TypeB_Indice = 'stuff'">
        <PartTwo indexlist="{count(//TypeA) + position()-1}">
            ... treatment ...
        </PartTwo>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And this is what my .xml looks like:

```
<Stuff>
    <Info>
        <TypeA> 
            <TypeA_Stuff/>
            <TypeA_Indice>xxx</TypeA_Indice>
        </TypeA>
        <TypeB>
            <TypeB_Stuff/>
            <TypeB_Indice>xxx</TypeB_Indice>
        </TypeB>
    </Info>
</Stuff>
```

**---------------------- edit ----------------------------**

The conditions for the PartOneBis is more complacated than the one I put in this code, there's more like 6 differents factor that can change its state from ok to not ok.
I was thinking of a for-each with an if and an incrementation but this don't work because you can't overwrite a variable or may be I'm wrong in my method.
If there's a way to count the node create before your point without having to create two .xml or use a c++ function I'll like to know it.

Thanks.

I need to put the "partOne" type first and the "partTwo" second but in the xml I've got, there's some conditions that makes that the TypeB is a partOne otherwise the other cases'll be a partTwo.

TypeA -> partOne

TypeB -> if (something) partOne  else partTwo

But the condition depend of several value which don't came from the same node but the wanted result is something like that

```
<PartOne indexlist="0">
        SomeStuff
</PartOne>
<PartOne indexlist="1">
        SomeStuff
</PartOne>
<PartTwo indexlist="2">
        SomeStuff
</PartTwo>
```

Comment: I don't understand your example. In general, you could create a variable selecting the nodes that meet your criteria. Then use this variable to count the nodes as well as to apply templates to them. You cannot count nodes after you have written them to the output tree - although you could write them to a variable first and then process that. But the first method is simpler and quicker.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I juste edit my post and tried to explain myself.
I'm kinda a newbie with xsl it's been only 2 mounth since I heared about it for the first time. Can you explain me how to apply your first solution?

Comment: Your XSLT code above is flawed.  1) Your top template is missing the `=` sign after `match`. 2) There is no such thing as `xsl:apply-template` -- you need an `s` on the end, to make that `xsl:apply-templates`. 3) Your `select` XPath expressions all attempt to match an `Info` element as the topmost element: `select="/Info/..."`  However, in your sample XML, the topmost element is `Stuff` instead -- so all of these `select` statements return nothing.

Comment: Also, you have two templates for handling `Info/TypeB` elements, one template with `mode="PartOne"` and the other with `mode="PartTwo"`.  However, both templates insert an element named `<PartOne ...>`.  Is this correct?  Or should the `mode="PartTwo"` template instead insert an element named `<PartTwo ...>`?

Comment: No, because I still don't understand your example. Try to simplify the problem as much as possible - and also show us the input and the expected output.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Thanks I edit it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k is it more understable now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it impossible to follow your example. Consider a simpler one:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item>red</item>
    <item>red red</item>
    <item>red blue</item>
    <item>red green</item>
    <item>blue</item>
    <item>blue blue</item>
    <item>blue green</item>
    <item>blue red</item>
    <item>green</item>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <xsl:variable name="red-items" select="item[contains(., 'red')]" />
    <xsl:variable name="blue-items" select="item[contains(., 'blue')]" />
    <output>
        <red-list>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$red-items"/>
        </red-list>
        <blue-list>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$blue-items">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="count($red-items)"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </blue-list>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:param name="n" select="0"/>
    <item i="{$n + position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </item>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <red-list>
    <item i="1">red</item>
    <item i="2">red red</item>
    <item i="3">red blue</item>
    <item i="4">red green</item>
    <item i="5">blue red</item>
  </red-list>
  <blue-list>
    <item i="6">red blue</item>
    <item i="7">blue</item>
    <item i="8">blue blue</item>
    <item i="9">blue green</item>
    <item i="10">blue red</item>
  </blue-list>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your time and this answer.